# CK Editor JSON file creation for inserting images

Tags: json, image, editor, ckeditor

I am using CK Editor on my web site and have built a simple uploader script in php to add images to my server. I am using the image browser plugin to enable the inclusion of images into my text. The image browser seems to work using a JSON file which must list all images in the image folder.

I am completely new to JSON and to get around learning how to build a JSON file I created a PHP file which simply reads the names of my images from a database and includes them in the JSON file.

This, as a workaround seems to be perfectly functional, however it is reliant on my upload script having to add the image names to the database (an unnecessary step) and it is also bad practice.

I am looking for a good tutorial or explanation on how to make a very simple JSON file which lists the images in my uploads folder in the correct format for CK Editor so that I can free myself from my image names database and program like a big boy.

Any and all help would be apreciated.